# Android direct user to the requested tab and function

Tags: android, notifications, android-tabhost

I have a tab host. When  notification come, I want to open the requested tab and at this tab activity i want to call a function. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: when notification come, i can set the requested tab. I can do this from main view where the tabhost exists. But requested tab is another activity. So from mainview i can not call a function where exists in the requested tab

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a particular tab from the TabActivity then do the following

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
```

Comment: Opening a requested tab is not a problem. The problem is after setting the requested tab, i want to call a function at this tab activity.

Comment: I guess you can call the method from your onCreate().